# Android NullPointerException: println needs a message

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, alarmmanager

I am working on a fake call app and i have given an option to place a quick call. I have all the logic of this option in the `quickCall()` method.

Here's the code of `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";

    ImageView imageView;
    EditText number, name;
    Button setTimeButton;
    ImageButton imageButton;
    TimePickerDialog timePicker;
    long selectedTimeInMillis;
    String enteredName, enteredNumber;

    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 100;

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PI = 1001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        setTimeButton = findViewById(R.id.set_time);
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.place_call_button);

        number = findViewById(R.id.number);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, SELECT_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        setTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                        selectedTimeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                        if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                            hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, hourOfDay + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Selected time in millis:" + selectedTimeInMillis);
                    }
                }, hour, minute, false);
                timePicker.show();
            }
        });

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enteredName = name.getText().toString().trim();
                enteredNumber = number.getText().toString().trim();
                if (enteredNumber.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter  a number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
                intent.putExtra("FAKE_NAME", enteredName);
                intent.putExtra("FAKE_NUMBER", enteredNumber);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE_PI, intent, 0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, selectedTimeInMillis, pendingIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your call has been placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.quick_call:
                quickCall();
                return true;

                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                if (imageUri != null) {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                }
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked any Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void quickCall(){

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        Intent quickCallIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);

        PendingIntent quickCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE_PI, quickCallIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis + 10000, quickCallPendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your call has been placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `AlarmReceiver` class

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String getFakeName = intent.getStringExtra("FAKE_NAME");
        String getFakeNumber = intent.getStringExtra("FAKE_NUMBER");

        Intent fakeRinger = new Intent();
        fakeRinger.setClassName("com.example.mani.fakecall", "com.example.mani.fakecall.FakeRinger");
        fakeRinger.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        fakeRinger.putExtra("USER_FAKE_NAME", getFakeName);
        fakeRinger.putExtra("USER_FAKE_NUMBER", getFakeNumber);
        context.startActivity(fakeRinger);

        Log.v("Fake name is", getFakeName);
        Log.v("Fake number is", getFakeNumber);
    }
}
```

And this is `FakeRinger` activity

```
public class FakeRinger extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView displayName, displayNumber, displayCarrier;
    ImageButton alarmOffButton;
    String carrierName;
    ImageView displayImage;

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fake_ringer);

        displayName = findViewById(R.id.display_name);
        displayNumber = findViewById(R.id.display_number);
        displayCarrier = findViewById(R.id.network_operator);
        displayImage = findViewById(R.id.display_image);

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (telephonyManager != null) {
            carrierName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
        }

        if (carrierName != null) {
            displayCarrier.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.incoming_call, carrierName));
        } else {
            displayCarrier.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.incoming_call));
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String userFakeName = intent.getExtras().getString("USER_FAKE_NAME");
        displayName.setText(userFakeName);

        String userFakeNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("USER_FAKE_NUMBER");
        displayNumber.setText(userFakeNumber);

        alarmOffButton = findViewById(R.id.hang_up_call);
        alarmOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                stopService(intent);
                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Whenever I click at the quick call option, my app crash. This is the error I am getting - `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.mani.fakecall.AlarmReciever: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are tryin to print values in your `LogCat`, and the values are null you get the error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

so you can validate a null value:

```
 Log.v("Fake name is", getFakeName!=null?getFakeName:"Not determinated");
 Log.v("Fake number is", getFakeNumber!=null?getFakeNumber:"Not determinated");
```

or just

```
if(getFakeName != null){
   Log.v("Fake name is", getFakeName);
}
if(getFakeNumber != null){
    Log.v("Fake number is", getFakeNumber);
}
```

---

If we look into the source code for `Log.v()`, a String value (not a null value) is required for the message:

```
public static int v(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
    return println(LOG_ID_MAIN, VERBOSE, tag, msg + '\n' + getStackTraceString(tr));
}
```

Comment: Why the -1 , please explain to improve any error in my answer

Comment: My reputation is less than 15, I cannot give you -1

Answer (score 0):

Just add check before printing values to logcat:

```
if(getFakeName != null)
    Log.v("Fake name is", getFakeName);
if(getFakeNumber != null)
    Log.v("Fake number is", getFakeNumber);
```

you need to pass a value to `Log.v()`, which can not be `null`

Answer (score -1):

Check if you declared AlarmReciever in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#receiving_broadcasts

Comment: check this: "Provide context for links
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."